# Rails NoMethodError in ProfilesController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Help pls. I have no idea how I got this error. I am trying to create a Profile for a User. The error seems to come from my create action for the profile. It looks ok to me but obviously it's not

error upon trying to create says:

```
undefined method `build_profile' for #<Profile:0x5ffcca0>
app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb:27:in `create'
```

Profile controller:

```
  class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @profiles = Profile.all
  end

  def edit
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  end

  def show
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @profile = Profile.new
    @profile.first_name = current_user.first_name
    @profile.last_name = current_user.last_name
    @profile.account_type = current_user.account_type
    @profile.email = current_user.email
  end

  def create
    @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)
      if @profile.save
        redirect_to root_path
      else
        render 'new'
      end
  end

  def update
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
      if @profile.update(profile_params())
        flash[:sucess] = "Sucessfully updated"
        redirect_to profile_path(@profile.id)
      else
        flash[:error] = "Error"       # Optional
        render "profiles/edit"
      end
  end

  def destroy
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    @profile.destroy!
    redirect_to "/profiles/show"
  end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit!
    end
end
```

Profile Model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    before_create :build_profile
end
```

Schema for Profile

```
create_table "profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "gender"
    t.date     "birthday"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "account_type"
    t.datetime "created_at",        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false
    t.string   "handedness"
    t.string   "coach"
    t.date     "date_joined"
    t.integer  "year"
    t.string   "course"
    t.string   "main_weapon"
    t.string   "additional_weapon"
    t.integer  "cellphone_number"
    t.integer  "emergency_contact"
    t.string   "contact_name"
    t.string   "contact_rel"
    t.string   "player_status"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end
```

Comment: Please provide the definition of `profile_params`.

Comment: Show your error message, full controller file, profile.rb and migration file.

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `build_profile` is not in your `Profile` class (i.e. `Model`), but you call it with a `before_create` callback:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    before_create :build_profile
end
```

You need yo define `build_profile` within the class (or include it from somewhere else, like a `module`):

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    before_create :build_profile

    private
    def build_profile
        # method code...
    end
end
```